# How to fully split a nested dictionary in as many columns as nesting levels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dict (built by me) called *dict3* with this structure: `A:[B1:[C1,C2,C3..],B2:[],B3:[C1],...]`. Although my problem is not related to the code used to write the dict, please find it next for the sake of your understanding:

```
dict3 = {} # Create an empty dictionary for us to populate

for key in swreq2pcr: # Iter over each of the keys in dict1
    subdict = {} # This will be the nested dictionary
    for item in swreq2pcr[key]: # Iter over each item in the list at that location in the dict
        if item[:4]=="PSAP":          
            subdict[item] = pcr2tests[item] # Get the corresponding list from dict2 and store it in the nested dictionary       
        else:
            subdict[item]=[]
    dict3[key] = subdict # store the nested dictionary
```

The ugly output obtained from the code above looks like the following:

[image]

To improve the look & feel I use the following code:

```
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)   #Avoid to truncate the dataframe

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i):dict3[i] 
                           for i in dict3.keys()},orient='index').stack().to_frame()
```

and the new and fancy output is:

[image]

where is much more easy to see the nesting. Although I was expecting two columns, and here is where I need support, by some reason the code only defines one column with name '0' as shown in the image below:

[image]

Hence, would you mind to help me to tailor the output to get something like the image below?. Thank you so much in advance.

[image]